University hosted Crypto conference: Looking for speakers and "society discount"
Hello I am a professor at a University in Chicago and we are hosting our annual forensics and security conference.   I am looking for speakers on the topic of cryptography and steganography - I would like to invite 1 or 2 top users here to be speakers as well as offer a "society discount" to any users interested in attending.   
My profile:
http://stackexchange.com/users/29929/jeremy-hajek
Conference URL http://forensecure.sat.iit.edu/

Is this kind of request on topic to ask here?   Last year I purchased an advertisement (banner add here and on the network security stackexchange) but I wanted to reach the community more direct this time?

Do you have a link to the conference?
I think asking on the main site would be off topic. We want clear, answerable questions on there. Asking who would be interested or who would be the best site users to invite would be off topic IMO. That said, the chat room might be a good place to ping certain users to see if they are interested. You can ping a particular person in the chatroom using @.

Ok I just added the URL I didn't want to flood the post with data if it was off topic.  I will try pinging them in chat and see what happens. Another question - would this be something for the stackexchange CHAOS group?  Are they still in existence?  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/intro-to-chaos-promotion-seminar/

I suppose meta is better for this than a question on the main site. Not sure what else could be done other than the question here.

@JeremyHajek: Hope you don't mind, I tweaked your meta-meta-question into the actual link you were suggesting. If people decide to close it then you'll have your answer, but personally I think that it's a perfectly acceptable question for meta.Crypto.  I agree with mike that in theory it would be nice to have on Chat, but in practice there aren't enough users in Crypto.SE to justify (a) pushing it 'down' to chat and (b) justify blocking it from meta

@mikeazo To keep Jeremy’s jacket clean – I’m the one to blame for this question being posted here, since I pointed OP to our Meta  when he asked in the chat. My fault… sorry. (I had the best intentions though.)

Hi.  I originally asked on the chat about this. e - sushi recommended to ask here.

@JeremyHajek Absolutely correct… that's why I already pointed out that fact a few minutes before you posted your comment… to make sure that everyone knows that if there's anyone to blame, it would be me.

@figlesquidge That “lack of active chat users” was my reasoning too when telling OP to maybe post it here. Thinking about it, it's scary to notice how much we seem to think alike sometimes. ;)

am in favor of flexible use of meta se-wide, glad to see an inquiry like this. however note google+ or reddit have many groups & may be a good place also.

@e-sushi, I was referring to asking on the main site, not necessarily on meta. I think whether or not this sort of thing should be allowed on meta should be left up to the community and so far the community has no problem with it.

@mikeazo Ah, OK… Understood. (+1) Just wanted to make sure he doesn't get a blow for what I recommended. But obviously, it turned out to be OK here on Meta… (pfew, I already started thinking I made a big mistake… thanks @ all for showing our true community spirit.)
